# display image dynamically from firebase in react native application

Tags: image, firebase, dynamic, react-native

I already extracted data from firebase and displaying them. Now i need to display images also. In firebase database i have the same structure as the image below [image]

And I have a folder under my project that contains all images with the exact same name like for an example "Carl.png"
I extracted the photo content in  and combined with the rest of the path : "Myproject/img/"+photo+".png" and it's displayed correctly in the screen. **But**  when i try to affect it to image i get errors. And here is the code i tried

```
<Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}} source={{uri : (this.props.item.imageName)}}> </Image>
```

and i get this [image] and if i try to put in                 `<Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}} source={{ uri: <Text> this.props.item.imageName </Text> }}> </Image>` i get this 
 [image]
 and if i put this code `source={require(this.props.item.imageName)}`  here is what i  get: u**nknown named module**

Answer (score 1):

Try loading it using require because you are loading it from a local storage, so your source attribute becomes:
source={ require('./img/'+photo+'.png') }

Comment: Thank you..** i just tried now and i get Unknown named module 'projectName/img/photos/Carl.png'  ** .. is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

try with 

`<Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}} source={{uri : (this.props.item.imageName)}} />`

You've got space between opening & closing tag.

Comment: Hi, thank you .. i tried your solution but i get nothing on the screen and i don't even get an error ..BUT on the console , i get this <Warning>: Could not find image named projectName/img/photos/Carl.png .. any idea

Comment: @user3521011 are you sure that you are using a full absolute url that is accessible from internet?

Comment: No , actually it's not from the internet : it's a folder under my project that contains all the photos with the exact same names in Firebase database. BUT, every time, i get an item from the database , i extract also it's photo (like Carl in the example above) and then concatenate it with (path under my project ) + photo + (.png)

Answer (score 0):

actually, React native does not support the dynamic images even if they are stored locally and you just need to make their name dynamically variable. So, the only solution that i was obliged to use was to use a massive switch case and here the code i used:

```
     switch (item.name) {
                case 'carl':
                    return (
                        <Image source{require('pathUnderProject/carl.png')}/>
                    );  
...
                default:
                    return (
                        <View >
                            <Text>{'Null'}</Text>
                        </View>
                    );
```

I know it's not the best solution, but at least i'm sure it's working fine and it won't break in the production environment